# Top and Bottom Pagination Sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I have some weird behavior with jQuery paginate plug-in (jPaginate). I need to have top and bottom pagination and I want to sync them - whenever one is clicked, the second one should be properly changed as well.

I have two divs with `number_pagination` class and they are initialized the same way:

```
$(".number_pagination").paginate(options);
```

Now, here where it gets weird. Whenever I click on the **top** div, everything works as supposed to, but if I click on the **bottom** one, it changes the bottom one and does the pagination, but the top one stays the same. I cannot figure out why that could be happening.

Here's the `onChange` function that is supposed to change both pagination divs. Note the `jQuery.fn.draw` function that is a part of jPaginate. This is where it applies classes and style.

```
  var opts=jQuery.extend({},jQuery.fn.paginate.defaults,options);
  var o=jQuery.meta?jQuery.extend({},opts,jQuery(this).data()):opts;

    jQuery(".number_pagination").each(function(){
                    var obj=jQuery(this);
                    jQuery.fn.draw(o,obj,page);
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Found another solution that works perfectly.

It may even work for other pagination plug-ins. It checks the class that has the currently selected page number and checks if the content matches the selected NOW page, and if it doesn't, it looks for siblings that have the correctly selected page and triggers the click event.

```
jQuery(".jPag-current").each(function(){
   if(jQuery(this).html() != page){
    jQuery(this).parent().siblings().children().each(function(){
      if(jQuery(this).html() == page){
      jQuery(this).trigger("click");
      }
   });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at using the onChange event to redraw the other pager that didn't incur the change